# Teradata error: The format or data contains a bad character

Tags: teradata

I get the error of "format or data contains a bad character" from the query below.  The datatype of column1 is `VARCHAR(2000)`.  This is an example of the string `'ROC 2236 00 ROC'` for column1 and the result I would like to get is `'2236.00'`

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,
      CASE WHEN COLUMN1 LIKE 'ROC%' THEN CAST(OREPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(SUBSTR('COLUMN1',5, 8),0)),' ','.' ) AS DEC(12,2) END           
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CAST(COLUMN1 AS DEC(12,2)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to test this without actual data, however at first glance, you are trying to convert the word column1 to a decimal...

and your where clause is doing a straight conversion and with sample data provided it would not like converting "ROC" to a decimal

try

```
SELECT 
     ORDER_NUMBER 
   , CASE WHEN COLUMN1 LIKE 'ROC%' THEN 
       CAST(OREPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,5, 8),0)),' ','.' ) AS DEC(12,2)) 
     END
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE CAST(OREPLACE(TRIM(COALESCE(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,5, 8),0)),' ','.' ) AS DEC(12,2)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found using the function `TRIM` to work better. I think the error is a result of leading/trailing spaces.